# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc

Running a spring mvc application using tomcat and hibernate in eclipse and Getting this error.

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0' must be of type [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice], but was actually of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0' must be of type [org.aopalliance.aop.Advice], but was actually of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor]
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:360)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.getAdvice(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:85)
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.getInterceptors(DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.java:78)
org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.java:61)
org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:482)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:188)
$Proxy18.savePerson(Unknown Source)
PersonService.savePerson(PersonService.java:15)
SpringMVCTest.addPersonFromForm(SpringMVCTest.java:58)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Have read that it could be a class loader error where there's duplication in the class path of two versions of Spring or two aop-alliance jars. This isn't the case in my case.

Here's my context xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />      
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="/"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" p:maxUploadSize="1000000" />

<bean id="personService" class="PersonService" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="/" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props> 
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManger" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a duplication of AOP Alliance jars? What if you remove it from `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor error in eclipse on my context xml.